ffmpeg python error when adding subtitles
When I run it I think there is an error with the subtitle path, but I can't solve it.
The error in terminal:

[Parsed_subtitles_0 @ 0000019bcc509780] Unable to parse option value
"UsersclaraDocumentsProyectosSubtitulossubtitulosDoctor Who - 1x05 The
Keys Of Marinus - Part 6 The Keys Of Marinus_track4_spa.srt" as image
size Error applying option 'original_size' to filter 'subtitles':
Invalid argument [vost#0:0/libx264 @ 0000019bce220480] Error
initializing a simple filtergraph Error opening output file
C:\Users\clara\Documents\Proyectos\Subtitulos\videos_con_subtitulos\Doctor
Who - 01x05f - The Keys of Marinus (The Keys of Marinus).mkv. Error
opening output files: Invalid argument

My code:
import os
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz
import ffmpeg

for video_file, (video, subtitle) in video_subtitle_mapping.items():
    print(f"Video: {video_file}, Subtitle: {subtitle}")

    folder_path = r"C:\Users\clara\Documents\Proyectos\Subtitulos\subtitulos"
    subtitulo_file = os.path.join(folder_path, subtitle)

    folder_path = r"C:\Users\clara\Documents\Proyectos\Subtitulos\videos"
    video_path = os.path.join(folder_path, video_file)

    folder_path = r"C:\Users\clara\Documents\Proyectos\Subtitulos\videos_con_subtitulos"
    output_video_file = os.path.join(folder_path, video_file)  # Output video file should have the same name as the input video

    try:
        ffmpeg.input(video_path).output(output_video_file, vf=f"subtitles='{subtitulo_file}'").run()
    except ffmpeg.Error as e:
        print(f"Error processing video {video_file}: {e.stderr}")

Add subtitles to MKVs

You're likely not escaping your characters correctly.  Check the subprocess arguments to debug (post it if you don't know what you're looking for)

I'm guessing the single quotes around the argument to subtitles= are wrong. You need them when there's a shell between you and ffmpeg, but there isn't one here (I imagine).
